# Replace Honeywell TH9320WF5003 with nest 3rd gen

Tags: nest

Need help with identifying wires on Honeywell TH9320WF5003, using Nest compatibility checker to replace with Nest gen 3

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the furnace/air-handler end of the thermostat cable?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like

- R is the Red wire
- W is the White wire
- G is the Green wire
- Y is the Yellow wire
- C is the Cerulean Blue wire

There is no standard to this, but there's a kind of obvious thing some people do, and it looks like they did it in your box.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. It worked with the way you described.